# Out Of Memory With Collection

Tags: .net, collections, out-of-memory

I am on .NET 4.0 so there is a 2 GB limit

This get is throwing an out of memory exception about 1/2 the time

```
public IEnumerable<FTSword7bitThesaurus> FTSwordsPlusSelected
{
    get
    {
        try
        {
            return FTSWords7bit.Select(w => new FTSword7bitThesaurus(this, w, selectedKeys.Contains(w.Key)));
        }
```

The stack trace begins:
System.Collections.Generic.List'1_setCapacity(int32 value)

This is the code that calls that get

```
<ListView Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="lvFTSWordsMine"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=lvThesarus, Path=SelectedItem.FTSwordsPlusSelected, Mode=OneWay}"
                              ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">
```

But what confuses me is FTSwordsPlusSelected (should be) smaller than FTSWords7bit

This is the only data in FTSword7bitThesaurus
One bool and two references

```
public class FTSword7bitThesaurus : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    bool selected = false;
    FTSword7bit fTSword;
    FTSthersarus fTSthersarus;
```

FTSWord7bit has on average 20 bytes of data
FTSWords7bit collection size is 12 million FTSWord7bit
That collection is not (yet) throwing an out of memory exception

I am getting the out of memory on the collection of what I think should be smaller objects
I can't profile the whole collection as the profiler balks

selectedKeys is is just a HashSet and never more than 10,000 and typically less than 200

Since clearly FTSWords7bit is created first do you think this is just due to memory fragmentation?

Any ideas on how to avoid this out of memory problem?

FTSWords7bit is used a lot and I hold on to that
FTSword7bitThesaurus is just used by one admin screen and I want it discarded when they exit that screen
Most of the time that collection is under 1 million but this is an odd data set
If I can just stabilize the 12 million I am OK
We can even live with the out of memory 1/2 the time but it does not instill confidence in the users
It is going to be a couple months before we go to .NET 4.5

From the accepted answer
The fix was just paging
Most likely the problem was a contiguous block of memory was not available

```
public void NextPage()
{
    page++;
    NotifyPropertyChanged("FTSwordsPlusSelected");
}

public IEnumerable<FTSword7bitThesaurus> FTSwordsPlusSelected
{
    get
    {
        try
        {
            return FTSWords7bit.Skip(page * pageSize).Take(pageSize).Select(w => new FTSword7bitThesaurus(this, w, selectedKeys.Contains(w.Key)));
        }
```

Comment: What profiler are you using?

Comment: @DavidKhaykin I don't even remember as I downloaded a free version and discarded it when it expired.   When I looked at individual objects the FTSword7bitThesaurus was like 1/2 the size.

Comment: How long does it take to get out of memory exception?

Comment: Was it RedGate ANTS Profiler by chance? If not I would give that one a shot, it's never failed for me before even profiling heavy web crawler apps that brought back tons of HTML data.

Comment: @DavidKhaykin Well that also can vary.  FTSWords7bit is built on demand from a db so that is like 20 seconds.   The get fails in about 20 seconds.  So if it fails on the first get then like 40 seconds.

Comment: I don't get how knowing the exact size of FTSword7bitThesaurus is going to help.  How can I pack more in a collection?

Comment: Profiler will help to show if object references aren't being discarded which can lead to memory problems. The thing that sticks out to me is your get function returns new Thesaurus (IEnumerable of them) and depending on how many times it's being called, that may be the cause.

Comment: @DavidKhaykin OK I agree.  I added a button to set the UI binding to null and call GC.collect.   That did seem to help.  I agree a profiler would help see what it going on.

Comment: You keep saying `collection`, but what kind of collection are you actually using?  If you JUST have the `.where()` statement, this would never get executed due to it being lazy... so how are you actually using it?

Comment: @Andrew FTSWords7bit is a List<FTSWord7bit>  The IEnumerable is used to populate a ListView / GridView.  I tried returning a List<FTSword7bitThesaurus> and that did not help.   I will post the code that binds to FTSwordsPlusSelected.

Comment: @Blam: As I'm certain you're aware... a `List<>` is actually an array...  Just for test purposes... have you tried to use a `LinkedList<>`.  While it WILL be slower, it would allow you to see if the OS is unable to find one giant contiguous block.

Comment: @Andrew Same error but LinkedList threw it 4/4 tries

Comment: @Blam Probably because a `LinkedList<>` has inherent overhead with each node.  I suspect the problem is the actual `ListView`.  Each entry is going to require memory on top of the memory your `List<>` requires.  So, the easy solution is to setup some sort of paging system.  Then use what you have with the `IEnumerable<>` and use `Skip()` and `Take()`.

Comment: @Andrew I think I agree.  The the stack trace does not have a line number and from debug I am pretty sure that was the last line of code behind called.  No idea how to set up some sort of paging system but I will give that a try.  Thanks   Maybe post that as an answer so I can check it off if I can make it work.

Comment: @Blam Good deal. I posted a bit more explanation of what I meant along with a post for "Data Virtualization".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies with the fact that not only does your code expect a very large contiguous block of memory (array via `List<>`), but it also has to allocate additional memory for each entry in the `ListView`.  I would imagine the overhead associated with the `ListView` is pretty steap, and is causing the problem.

There lie a few solutions with a varying grade of complexity:

- **Data Virtualization** - This solution is the best for your users.  Essentially, the control will only keep the rows it needs in memory.  Your users won't be able to tell of course, so this is the best and most complicated solution.  This [post](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34405/WPF-Data-Virtualization) has a decent example.  (It looks like a Google image search).
- **Control Paging** - This solution looks more like a website option.  Think about normal Google, they don't show you an infinite results, just a subset.  They then let you pick the next page for more results.  This can be done pretty well with an `IEnumerable<>` because you can use `Skip()` and `Take()` for each page (Say you have 25 entries per page, then you would do `Skip(25 * pageNumber).Take(25)`).  I find this solution far easier to create but more of a burden to use.

Comment: It is an admin screen and not used often.  Most data has less than 1 million rows.  I just added buttons to grab a million rows at a time.  Because of UI level virtualization I am not sure the ListView is a problem.

Comment: Actually now that you mention it I always thought all wpf listviews use data virtualization already. Maybe just taking advantage of that would solve the issue.

Comment: From what I understand ListView virtualization is a UI virtualization only (and I like it working that way).   And it appears if you send it an IEnumerable it will create a List.

Comment: I haven't looked at it in a while... but I thought that post I sent you used a `ListView` to virtualize it.  I also thought it didn't grab the ENTIRE IEnumerable.

Comment: This is adding no clarity. Yes I use ListView (with virtualization) and don't think I have stated otherwise.  If it (ListView) was not grabbing ENTIRE IEnumerable then why would I get OOM at 12 million but not 10 million.  Breaking it up into 1 million row pages fixed it.